# Extract part of image

Tags: python, opencv

I want to extract the images inside the photo frames. For the first [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO3yy.png) I want to extract the deer, car, plane and boat. For the second [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TmDi.png) I want to extract the bird. I am using openCV in python, but this is new to me.

I have started with transforming the images into greyscale and the using the edge detector `cv2.Canny()`, but from here I don't really know how to continue, any tips? Would also really appreciate some code / pseudocode.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python/OpenCV cv2.matchTemplate can ignore parts of the image when doing the template matching by using a mask image. In your case, you need a mask that is white for the frame and black inside. It only allows the mask for certain  comparison metrics. See the documentation at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga586ebfb0a7fb604b35a23d85391329be

An example is at [How to template match a simple 2D shape in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61779288/how-to-template-match-a-simple-2d-shape-in-opencv/61780200#61780200)

Another simpler example is at [cv2.matchTemplate finds wrong template in image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59759374/cv2-matchtemplate-finds-wrong-template-in-image/59779209#59779209)